# Find basis of subspace $A^t = -A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I stumbled upon a question I don't know how to tackle
Given a matrix $A \in M_{3 \times 3}$ (All $3 \times 3$ matrices)
Find a basis for subspace $W = \{A \in M_{3 \times 3} \mid A^{t}= -A\}$

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: This is *very* hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [skew symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix). They look like $(a_{ij})=(-a_{ji})$, which also means that the diagonal entries are zero.

It turns out that they form a subspace, which is very easy to show by explicitly checking addition and scalar multiplication.

The usual basis for matrices is to identify them with $\mathbb R^9$, and let the basis be the matrix with $1$ in a single entry, and $0$ everywhere else. Here, we don't  need any of the diagonals since they are zero. Really, since every matrix is determined by it's lower diagonal, we really only need $3$ basis vectors. Here is one of them:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

---

I mentioned how to deduce thaat this is the basis. We are looking to construct a basis for matrices that essentially look like
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

So there is essentially only one way to go in terms of a basis.

---

If you find this totally unsatisfying, I guess we could use the fact that
$$2A=(A-A^T)+(A+A^t)$$
so that the right side is symmetric and the left side is skew symmetric.

So in particular the vector space $Mat_{3 \times 3}$ splits as a direct sum 
$$Mat_{3 \times 3}=Sym \bigoplus Skew$$

We can use the above construction to deduce the basis if you know the identification $Mat_{3 \times 3} \cong \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}=\mathbb R^9$ with basis $1$ in a single entry and $0$ everywhere else (denote it $a_{ij}$). From this, take a basis vector and decompose it in the direct sum
$$a_{ij}=(a_{ij}-a_{ij}^t) + (a_{ij}+a_{ij}^t)=(a_{ij}-a_{ji}) + (a_{ij}+a_{ji})$$
and take the RHS of the summand $(a_{ij}-a_{ji})$  to find a basis for the skew symmetric matrices. Notice that this is zero when $i=j$ on the diagonal, and you get repeats when you apply the process to $(a_{ij}-a_{ji})=(a_{ji}-a_{ij})$, so you still genuinely get $3$ linearly independent vectors.

Note also this process has nothing to do with $3 \times 3$ matrices and generalizes readily (as with the previous method.)

Comment: Yes i found the basis \begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0 \end{pmatrix} but how would you elegantly solve this problem algebraicly, i personally just guessed and check both conditions (span & independence)

Comment: What do you mean "algebraically." There is no reason to suspect a purely algebraic solution, since a choice of basis essentially brings us to matrix algebra.

Comment: @Whiteclaws well, I added a little bit, since I really dont think you should be "guessing" here. I hope that it is helpful